# In Elasticsearch, why does my query string overmatch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm inserting my data as follows:

```
PUT my_index2/doc/1
{
  "key": "party",
  "str_val": "THE TWITTER INC"
}

PUT my_index2/doc/2
{
  "key": "party",
  "str_val": "twitter inc"
}
```

This query:

```
POST my_index2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "str_val",
      "query": "*twitter*"
    }
  }
}
```

correctly returns both results. If I slightly alter my query to:

```
POST my_index2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "str_val",
      "query": "*the twitter*"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting only one result since `*the twitter*` should only match "THE TWITTER INC" and not "twitter inc". But two results are returned.

Why is my search returning too many matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `default_operator` for [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) is `OR`. You can always use `explain:true` to know how the result was returned. Like below:

```
POST my_index2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "str_val",
      "query": "*the twitter*"
    }
  },
  "explain": true
}
```

For your case, you need to explicity mention `AND` to return only documents where both terms match i.e. `the` AND `twitter`

```
 POST my_index2/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "default_field": "str_val",
          "query": "*the twitter*",
           "default_operator": "AND"
        }
      }
    }
```